# How to modify x-axis in ggplot with a given vector of labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + 
  geom_line()
```

Which create the following plot

[image]

What I want to do is to replace the x-axis (`speed`) values: `5,10,15,20,25` into the following vector: `c("-5000", "-2500", "FOO", "2500", "5000")`.

But why this failed?

```
 ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_line() + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("-5000", "-2500", "TSS", "2500", "5000"))
```

It produces this:

[image]

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `scale_x_continuous()` because speed is a continuous variable. You also need to specify the breaks, i.e., where to place the ticks.

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25), 
                     labels = c("-5000", "-2500", "TSS", "2500", "5000"))
```

[image]